# Why did all of my holiday stuff disappear from Tiny Death Star?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

Why did my holiday stuff all disappear? I was using it earlier  and then I opened up TDS and it was gone.

Comment: I just started this decoration thing today, and so far I've lost all my decorations three times in the past twelve hours. The first time I lost 8 decorations. This last time it was only 3. Midnight has nothing to do with it, though I did once see a scene of Vader watching while the Emperor removed the decorations from the Arrival floor.

Comment: I have seen several other reports this phenomenon.  People are reporting that they are unable to keep their status on the Holiday Decorations.  Some are saying that it happens when they exit out of the game.  Others are saying that they are seeing a scene with the Emperor ripping down their decorations.

It appears to be a bug.  Can people please post what platform they are using.  In my case, I am using iOS 7.  And, I managed to close the program for several hours without an issue.

Comment: It just happened to me.  I had about 45 levels decorated and when I turned on the game and the Emperor and Darth Vader cleared the decorations.

Comment: I'm thinking now that this is a "feature".  I've seen the Emperor cutscene now four times - always when jumping into the app.  I think it is random if/when it appears, but it always seems to happen when opening the app.  Whatever the probability is that triggers it, it is way too high.  I don't see how one could get 35 levels decorated without spending real money on bux (which I refuse to do).  I think before I thought it was a glitch because I'm playing on my phone (Nexus 4), and I often load the game, look away at other stuff, then look back.  The cutscene is very short and easy to miss.

Comment: I would be curious if people playing this game on a more stable platform experience this as often.  Unfortunately, it seems, I'm playing it on my phone (Android; Nexus 4) so can't really leave it running (between the screen shutting off to conserve battery, to phone calls, to using the phone for other purposes, TDS is often cycled to the background).

Comment: Good news! There was an update for the game pushed today!  In the changelog: "Fixes loss of holiday decorations".  Fingers crossed it doesn't happen again until the 26th!

Comment: @Twitch_City verification?

Comment: @Braiam See here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lucasarts.tinydeathstar_goo (under "What's New").

Comment: I'd just consider this a feature, really. Star Wars and the holidays have not mixed well, [historically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Christmas_special).

Comment: @Twitch_City can you post that as answer.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an event that is now over.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to [Twitch_City](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/61602/twitch-city) for the [update](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/146098/why-did-all-of-my-holiday-stuff-disappear-from-tiny-death-star/146553#comment198025_146098):

Today, December 16, the makers of Tiny Death Star, Lucas Arts, released a new update that should fix the issue:

> Fix to Tower reset issues. **If you continue to have problems please contact support**.
>
> Fixes loss of holiday decorations.

Source: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lucasarts.tinydeathstar_goo

Answer (score -3):

I am not 100% sure, but I think i found the problem.  The emperor would only tear down my holiday progress after I had tried to earn more Imp. Bux

Comment: I don't think the appearance of the Emperor has anything to do with earning bux - I think it is just a random occurrence that the game checks for every time it is loaded.