# Is there a special technique to get more Decoration Droids in Tiny Death Star?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I'm just wondering if there is anything I can do in game to increase the amount of decoration droids appearing in my elevator without actually spending bux on them? If there is not, how long would it take to get 35 decoration droids? I read elsewhere that a user got all 35 droids in 1 sitting, however I've been constantly bringing bitizens to their preferred floor for over 2 hours now and have only gotten 8 droids including the free one it gives you. Did the other user play the game for like 10 hours straight or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: The other guy probably either spent real money on bux, or he probably sat there for a very long time. I've noticed in the about... 3 hours of play I've had today, I've gotten about 6. So I think it's just random.

Comment: Okay great thanks, well it's almost bedtime, I'm going to set an alarm early tomorrow morning and hopefully get all 35 as I heard sadly the droids reset the following day, hopefully I can get 10 bf bed though. Thanks

Comment: Not a problem, and good luck!

Comment: AFter looking a bit, you shouldn't have to worry about a reset anymore, if I'm reading this correctly. http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/146098/why-did-all-of-my-holiday-stuff-disappear-from-tiny-death-star

Comment: Wow well that's a relief. I mean this game was designed to play in couple minute intervals throughout the day...HaHa, even though I tend to find myself playing this game for hours on end. I mean I was up for the challenge of getting 35 in 1 day but this makes my life a whole lot easier. And hey if it still resets a couple of times that's fine. They have 21 days to fix the problem if it persists and I'm very excited to rake in rewards. Thanks again, now I can sleep in.

Comment: I did manage to play long enough to get the 35 without a reset.  But, as the previous commenters noted, there is now a fix in place.  Good luck and welcome to the site!

Comment: Weird...mine reset after 6 or so, and then I haven't gotten a single one in the past 2 days (updated to the latest version).

Comment: I wish they would give you back all of your decorated levels that you lost the first time.  I was liking those extra bux!!!!

Comment: so far i've gotten 19 floors decorated, have exited the games multiple time and even shut off my device. It's also been more than 24 hours and I still have not lost any decorations...touch wood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from paying 4 Bux, there is no way to actually increase the number of decorator droids that visit your Death Star.  They are randomly generated like all of the other VIPs.

Obviously, this is no longer a critical matter since the most recent update.  But, for completeness, I wanted to post an answer to this question.